# Optimal way to pick the starting $x$ when computing the square root with the Babylonian method

Tags: radicals

I was reading the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) given in the Wikipedia article for the Babylonian method of computing the square root, and I wondered why did they set the starting $x_0$ to 600:

> To calculate $\sqrt S$, where S = 125348, to six significant figures, use the rough estimation method above to get:
>
> $x_0 = 6 * 10^2$ = 600.000

Did they pick 6 because the number $S$ has 6 digits, and multiplied by $10^2$ to get a number that has half as many digits as $S$?

**Update**: another reason I'm asking is that I've seen this [algorithm](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/d8817cb600381319992d7caa038bf4faceb1097f/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L727-L751) that calculates the square root efficiently, but which lacks explanatory comments. I am fairly confident that what it does is compute the square root as if the input was a perfect square of a power of two, but I'm not sure if that's the optimal way in a wider mathematical sense.

Answer (score 2):

In that section, it says that the number $6$ is for numbers in the form $\sqrt{S} = \sqrt{a} \cdot 10^n$, where $10 < a < 100$.

To minimise the absolute error (say $5$ is $3$ more than $2$), we take the arithmetic mean $\frac{\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{100}}{2} \approx 6.58$, and to minimise the relative error (say $5$ is $2.5$ times that of $2$), we take the geometric mean $\sqrt[2]{\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{100}} \approx 5.62$. Therefore, as a rough estimate to $1$ significant figure, $6$ is the value that minimises both the arithmetic and the geometric mean.